# why Object.keys(data).sort() not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sort my object keys.

But when I'm printing my object, it always print  `bb` first. Can anyone explain this?

It should print `aa` first ? I already sorted my keys.

My first key should be `aa` and then second should be `bb`.

Here is my code

```
var data = {
    bb:"bb",
    aa:"cc"
};
Object
    .keys(data)
    .sort();
console.log(data)
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/43ax8oz1/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

- objects in JS have no order of elements, like arrays do
- `Object.keys` returns an array of object keys, it does not modify the object itself, see the following example:

```js
var data={bb:"bb",aa:"cc"};
var arr = Object.keys(data);
arr.sort();
console.log(arr); // the array IS modified, 
                  // but it has nothing to do with the original object
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var data={bb:"bb",aa:"cc"};
var keys = Object.keys(data);
keys.sort();

var obj = {};
for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  obj[keys[i]] = data[keys[i]];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not any method for sorting object keys in JavaScript but you can do this by a object prototype like this.

```js
Object.prototype.sortKeys = function () {
        var sorted = {},
        key, a = [];
    
        for (key in this) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                a.push(key);
            }
        }
    
        a.sort();
    
        for (key = 0; key < a.length; key++) {
            sorted[a[key]] = this[a[key]];
        }
        return sorted;
    }

    var data = {bb: "bb", aa :"cc"};
    
    alert(JSON.stringify(data.sortKeys())); // Returns sorted object data by their keys
```